# When the running time of a smallest grammar algorithm is $O(|\Sigma|^{\log_2(|s|)})$ for input $s$.

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity, np-complete

Suppose I could prove that the running time of a smallest grammr algorithm were $O(|\Sigma|^{\log_2(|s|)})$.  Then is that considered a polynomial-time algorithm, or exponential in the context of the $P = NP$ problem?

$\Sigma = $ the minimal alphabet of $s$.

I'm looking for someone who has a link or can explain how they showed that *smallest grammar problem* is NP-complete.  When they showed this, did they consider a fixed alphabet size, and it is NP-complete with respect to input length $|s|$ only?  Or...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that $a^{\log(b)}= b^{\log(a)}$. Thus we have:

$$O(|\Sigma|^{\log_2(|s|)}) = O(|s|^{\log_2(|\Sigma|)})$$

In other words, as long as *either* the alphabet or the size of the $s$ does not grow without bound, your algorithm is polynomial complexity, as the exponent will simply be constant.

Comment: I see that, with less rigor yes.  But enough for me to ask the question.  If *that* is the running time.  Then would P = NP, or is the P=NP question still open after that?

Comment: @EnjoysMath _Generally_ $\Sigma$ is taken to be constant.

Comment: Can you prove $a^{\log(b)} = b^{\log(a)}$ or do you have a link?  I've never seen that before!

Comment: Where is the reference that I would cite to say that is the case?  Is it a popular book that says that?